# MVC 5 Identity and Google Auth consent screen - minimal permissions and no email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

When signing in to Stack-overflow, for example, you get the following consent screen:
[image]

1.In my consent screen settings I must give my email. How can I make it so that no email is      displayed or a **non-gmail** email address is displayed ?

2.My consent screen asks for email and basic info. I want it to only ask for email. Where in my MVC app I can config the google authentication to only request email permission ?

**EDIT**:
Regarding question 2, I found the answer:

```
var googleAuthOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions();
            googleAuthOptions.Scope.Add("openid email");
```

Comment: Short answer is that you can't: What gets asked for is canned in the ASP.NET OAuth code. However, that code is open source, and you could copy bits out of it to do your own implementation - it's not that hard.

Comment: @slippyr4 I actually managed to do that. Added it to the question.